Executing sfc.exe /scannow on Remote Computer Using PowerShell Doesn't Show Process
I'm attempting to run sfc.exe /scannow on a remote computer using PowerShell's Start-Process, but I'm unable to confirm whether the process starts on the remote machine. When I check for any sfc processes using Get-Process sfc, I don't see any processes running. How can I effectively start sfc.exe /scannow on a remote machine using Start-Process?
Here's the PowerShell code I'm using:
$remoteComputer = "RemoteComputerName"

$scriptBlock = {
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\windows\system32\sfc.exe" -ArgumentList "/scannow" -NoNewWindow -Wait
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteComputer -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock

Update:
If I start it like this it works, but do I do it with Start-Process?
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteComputer -ScriptBlock {& $(${env:Windir} + "\System32\SFC.EXE") "/scannow"}


Why are you using Start-Process? It sounds like simply running sfc.exe /scannow directly might solve your problem (or at least reveal why the process dies too quickly)

@MathiasR.Jessen I want to "start-process -nonewwindow" so I can start "invoke-command -asjob" on multiple computers and then check if the tasks are complited with "get-job -IncludeChildJob"

I don't think Start-Process will make a difference here. Try changing it to just sfc.exe /scannow, run it and see what happens :)

Okay, so it works when you just run it directly. Why do you still want to use Start-Process then? What change in behavior are you hoping to get from using Start-Process instead?

@MathiasR.Jessen Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteComputer -ScriptBlock {SFC.EXE /scannow} I ckecked it doesn't create a process and yes, Start-Process with -nonewwindow param suppose to make a difference

How are you testing that "it doesn't create a process"? If you do Get-Process after sfc.exe has returned then you obviously won't find anything - because the Get-Process call is only reached after the process exits :)

@MathiasR.Jessen isn't -nonewwindow param redirect output to console? And a script won't go further until sfc is completed?

@MathiasR.Jessen "-ScriptBlock {& $(${env:Windir} + "\System32\SFC.EXE") "/scannow"}" - creates process. "-ScriptBlock {SFC.EXE /scannow}" - doesn't create a process. I'm testing by "Enter-psssession $remoteComputer" then get-process sfc
